# Asymptotic solution of a fourier transform for large $t$

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

I would like to find how this function decays as a function of $t$

$$\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty } w e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}}H_0^{(2)}(w r) e^{i t w}  \, dw\right)$$

[image]

This is what it looks like for r=20. I would like to find out how it decays for large $t$ ($t>22$ for example). I do not know if this integral can be evaluated exactly, but regardless of that I would interested in learning how one might be able to figure out the solution for this asymptotically.

Comment: What is $H_0^{(2)}$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas i would suspect that this is a Hankelfunction of the second kind, but clarification is indeed needed

Comment: It is the hankel function of the second kind.

Comment: ah ok...then the leading order asymptotics is $-2/t^2$ as far as i can see

Comment: @tired Can you explain why?